# We need to talk about Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I would start this post with something along the lines of "without naming names", but I think it's time to pinpoint the issues we currently face in chat and take action.

This is a follow-up to [The state of chat](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8771/the-state-of-chat). This post aims to identify specific problems and specific problematic users. Because nothing has changed.

#### Self-Promotion

A post / series of post by a user clearly affiliated with the content linked to (not exclusive to PPCG) for the sole or main purpose of promoting said content. This becomes a problem, when it is noticed by many different users. It's a *serious* problem, when this behavior persists, even after the user(s) has been asked to stop.

A few examples of recent responses that have gone unnoticed as it seems:

> Can you stop advertising your answers in here ? ([21 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32361573#32361573))
>
> Quit "shamelessly" promoting your posts. At this point, you should be ashamed. ([9 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32555458#32555458))
>
> TNB is not a place to advertise your posts, whether on PPCG or elsewhere ([13 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32553416#32553416))
>
> As much as I like the bots, they have a separate room(s) for a reason. I don't mind a quote every now and then, but we don't need a running update ([6 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32506341#32506341))

**Deleting Messages**

A user keeps deleting chat messages with no apparent reason. This becomes a problem, when the amount of deletions is unjustified, the flow of the conversation becomes disrupted and/or users joining the chatroom become disoriented as to why these messages have been deleted.

> For heavens sake, stop deleting your messages. ([5 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32321615#32321615))
>
> A good alternative to deleting a message that you didn't think before posting, is to think before posting ([19 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32321663#32321663))

This becomes a *serious* problem, when the deleted messages actually were relevant and exhibit a higher quality than most of the other content posted by that user.

> [...] I don't get why you would delete a legitimate question, but regularly post nonsensical messages containing nothing but bad English and crying smilies. You should really start to think about your signal to noise ratio. ([6 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32538014#32538014))

#### Intentionally Lowering Quality

A user posts messages that add nothing to the conversation. Worse yet, the contain nothing but

- (redundant) text emoticons
- intentionally bad English
- questions that the user doesn't really need answers to
- straight up noise

This is always a *serious* problem, and I'll explain why. A few months ago, when chat was quiet, a message occasionally appeared indicating something like "the last message was posted xh ago".

Now these messages have been replaced by "conversations" that are completely uncalled for, useless and a bad example for any user. Instead of an interesting chat log, followed by a brief period of silence, new users now encounter the worst side of TNB when visiting during these (previously) quiet periods. This influences other users.

> [...] Spamming the room with noise will not be tolerated. ([37 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=31242429#31242429))
>
> [...] Please don't speak like this. It lowers the tone of one of the few (usually) civilized places on the internet. ([14 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=31734585#31734585))
>
> [in response to a message containing nothing but noise] unnecessary ([4 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32514741#32514741))

#### Arrogance, Drama<sup>[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0IqR.png)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=drama&Room=240&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=stars)</sup>

> Nobody said that. Don't create drama for no reason ([9 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32506624#32506624))
>
> Stop it already with the artificial drama! ([7 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=30916483#30916483))
>
> I don't mind having you in this room, but sometimes I wonder if you're just intentionally trying to create drama that wasn't there. ([6 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=30934732#30934732))

Did you notice how all three above are directed at the same user? Over an unacceptably long period of time? Weird, seeing how their response to my statement

> You'd think that after being repeatedly called out for sub-optimal behaviour in chat, one would try to reflect and improve. But somehow that doesn't seem to apply to a few members here. ([link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32306790#32306790))

was

> Me excluded. :{ [...], however, included.

which is provably false and defintely

> a bit arrogant. ([2 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32306810#32306810))

#### Users

We all know who the users are that cause all of these and more problems. But let's take a look at the messages per user in *Trash* that have been manually moved there by a mod:

```
TùxCräftîñg:             95
LegionMammal978:         56
CrazyPython:             22
Matthew Roh:             16
EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ:             16 (mostly msgs containing only carets)
R. Kap:                  15
Erik The Golfer:         14
CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ:            9
betseg:                  8
Molarmanful:             8
BusinessCat:             7
Destructible Watermelon: 7
dorukayhan:              6
Bálint:                  5
Mars Ultor:              3
zyabin101:               3
```

The root of basically all noise and low quality messages is TùxCräftîñg. Despite them being relatively "new", they already hold the questionable record of the most messages *so bad* they are already trashed.

zyabin101 is also on that list. But rather than posting straight up nonsense, they like to stir up trouble (see above evidence) and are generally completely resistant to any kind of notice by other users about their behavior. Here's a recent example of what I mean:

> @zʏᴀʙiɴ101 Please don't answer for other people. ([link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=30140641#30140641))
>
> @zyabin101 Why do you always answer for other people. ([link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=31429338#31429338) and then again [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=31429517#31429517) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=31429520#31429520) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32378783#32378783))
>
> @zyabin101 minxomat still has a very valid point that you should probably not answer for other people. ([link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32379239#32379239))

And just denying it even when caught in the act:

[image: chat screenshot]

#### What to do

See my answer for my suggestions.

The question for you is:

- What specific action can be taken to mitigate this behavior?
- What is our long term strategy?

IMO it's time to define hard(er) limits for this behavior (i.e. *when* to apply a ban etc.). Tips like "set an example" prove to be a bit useless, because that (apparently) does *nothing* to improve overall quality. Use the linked meta question for such tips. This question is more aimed at moderators.

Comment: This is one of the few times when I wish I could off a bounty on meta, haha. Thanks for bringing this up, it's a *very* important discussion to have, and I agree with pretty much all of your points.

Comment: I agree with this entire post. I used to hang out in chat here and there because I was interested in learning about new golfing tips or new esolangs. I haven't in months because of exactly this kind of behaviour.

Comment: zyabin101, after being called out then said "@EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ @/all Please don't think I'm annoying.
Or you'd get in my ignore list." [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30140655#30140655) ... and later in response to mınxomaτ [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31429527#31429527)

Comment: "(redundant) text emoticons" Could you give some examples of this? I am not entirely sure what you mean by redundant, because they convey a certain tone that would otherwise be conveyed with emphasis.

Comment: I agree with the post. Some of the maturity issues in chat may come from physical immaturity. Some of the users are in their teens, and lack of experience (or discipline) could contribute to sending immature messages/responses. But that's no excuse to not learn. With all the professionals spending their time in TNB during work hours, there's plenty of people to use as role models when it comes to chat.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I mean literally multiple (prolonged) emoticons in a single message.

Comment: @mbomb007 I would wager that being a teen does not necessitate a lack of maturity, though I would say that immaturity lies mostly amongst that age group.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to link to all these examples! This is especially useful for users that live in a different time zone and don't read through the whole transcript to know what's going on.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien There's some good evidence of that, e.g. Doorknob. You. I like to think I am also good evidence of that.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem This is true--and you are certainly very mature, and make a good case..

Comment: "The root of basically all noise and low quality messages is TùxCräftîñg" Proof needed. While he's definitely the person that I have seen post the most non-sense and self-promotion in chat, it doesn't mean he's the only one generating such conversations. I see other names in the table you show that are also responsible, and not just "TùxCräftîñg followers".

Comment: @Fatalize That wording is less than ideal. It's not that he is generating all the noise - he is generating the vast majority of the noise.

Comment: @MorganThrapp if it's putting people off chat that makes the case stronger. Is there anyone else who stays away or chats less frequently because of the noise?

Comment: (By which I mean "please comment here if you do")

Comment: I often self promote my sandboxed posts? Is that acceptable?

Comment: @BetaDecay I would say this is acceptable if you haven't had enough feedback on it. "Promoting" it after 5 minutes in the sandbox is bad.

Comment: @BetaDecay I'd like to actually extend that further.  We have 3 feeds into TNB:  New questions, new sandboxed posts, new meta questions.  If *any* of those aren't getting feedback after a good amount of time, feel free to post it.

Comment: I did **NOT** know so many of my messages were being moved to trash. I'll try to keep it down.

Comment: On the other hand I did deliberately post messages directly into Trash (not moved). Maybe that's why it's at 22.

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython No. I specifically excluded messages in Trash that were not moved. Though you improved greatly over the past few months.

Comment: @mınxomaτ If I did, I didn't realize it.

Comment: Messages posted to messages trashed ratio?

Comment: Could you please provide the query used?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In light of recent issues, two users have been suspended for 7 days. Please *Be Nice* and don't discuss their suspensions.

Remember that chat flags are visible to all 10k users on the entire network, and even moderator-only chat flags are visible to *all* SE moderators in chat. Therefore, use them only for events that require *immediate* intervention.

In the absence of a way to notify only PPCG moderators in chat, you can flag any post of a user on the main site instead, using the *in need of moderator intervention* options and a custom flag reason. If the affected user hasn't posted on main, you can flag one of your own posts instead.

Comment: They're only visible while there are messages in the flag queue. After a flag has been raised and before it gets handled, a blue circle what displays the number of pending flags appears in a corner of your avatar.

Comment: Ok, thanks! =) Do you know if I get to see chat flags even if I'm not in a SO chat room too? I've never noticed it before... I'm assuming it's the avatar on the left side in chat...

Comment: Yes, that avatar. Chat SO and chat SE seem to be pretty much decoupled, but you have more than 10k rep on both, so you should see flags wherever they're raised. Flags aren't frequent though and usually get handled in a few seconds.

Comment: @WeeingIfFirst Quill made a neat tool called [PopcornSE](https://github.com/The-Quill/PopcornSE) that allows 10k network users to see chat flags after they have already been handled.

Answer (score 23):

> This is one of those situations where I feel a temporary chat ban would be in order ([3 stars](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=32538209#32538209))

Exactly. Just because chat is a general discussion, doesn't mean the discussion has to be *this* low quality. We learned over the past few months, that giving tips to users to better themselves is not very effective.

So I suggest:

- keep trashing conversations that have no place in TNB and thus raise the quality new users experience in our chatroom
- start applying chat bans if users refuse to respond to criticism (especially if that criticism comes from a moderator)

Comment: how would this be enforced? chat room moderation is almost micromanaging.

Comment: @tuskiomi Perhaps with a flag to draw the attention of mods. TùxCräftîñg and zyabin101 are lowering the quality of TNB, so it's a valid reason to flag.

Comment: Although tips on how to improve are not always effective, I'd prefer to be part of a community that gives such tips. If the tips are rejected then yes removing problem users seems necessary, but I have also seen the positive side, where users thank people for feedback and amend their behaviour immediately.

Comment: @mbomb007 Flags for moderator attention in chat will get declined in these cases. They are visible to all moderators of Stack Exchange, and unless it is handled by a TNB regular, they won't see the big picture.

Comment: Since it's my message you quoted, I agree of course. I propose handing out a week-long chat ban to the problem users.

Comment: @mbomb007 Besides, I thought that it wasn't the moderators' jobs to police chat

Comment: @BetaDecay Chat is as much moderated by moderators as the rest of the network.

Comment: Lets be honest: everybody ignores people outside their "group". The chat has this very strict set of people. Anyone outside it, won't even have a chance to talk on the chat. People just say trash for attention, in my opinion. Fix this, you fix had of the problems there. This is my opinion.

Comment: _"start applying chat bans if ..."_ I disagree with the *if*. Apply them *now*. Ban TuxCrafting and zyabin101. mınxomaτ's post is not evidence that we need to start paying attention to these trouble-makers; it's evidence that we've been letting them get away with this stuff for **far** too long. IMO mınxomaτ has pointed out more than enough behavior from these users to merit a week-long chat ban like @Mego said.

Comment: @Lynn I agree. It's time for the new room owners to show their teeth.

Comment: @Lynn I fully agree. It's now far beyond any kind of reasonable limit. I will resort to drawing mod's attentions to chat whenever there's an issue (that's all I can do). BTW, [here's a recent](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32671154#32671154) incident that happened in response to your comment. smh