# New TNB Room Owners: Nominations Phase

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

It was decided by community consensus that [we need more room owners for The Nineteenth Byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10920/45941). The process for choosing the new room owners will be as follows:

- For one week (lasting until UTC midnight on January 28th), nominations will be accepted on this meta post. The votes on the nominations here will not matter. Self-nominations are allowed. If you are nominated by someone else, you must accept the nomination to be considered a candidate (we don't want to elect someone who doesn't actually want the position).
- After the nomination period, the election will begin, lasting for one week (until UTC midnight on February 4th). At the end of the election, the 4 candidates with the most votes will be submitted to the moderators and current room owners for approval and instatement as new room owners.

In each nomination post, please include:

- The user being nominated
- Common active times in chat
- A short blurb about why the user is a good choice for becoming a room owner

Comment: Would it make sense to apply some policies similar to the moderator elections for this? Primarily that users with recent (define recent?) chat suspensions are not eligible?

Comment: @MartinEnder Possibly, though it would require some help from the mods to verify chat suspensions.

Comment: @MartinEnder I don't think so. Why make users with recent chat suspensions ineligible? If the community wants to support a user with a recent chat suspension, I don't understand why we would take that option away.

Comment: @Rainbolt This is in line with my original thinking. If the community thinks an individual is unfit for being a room owner, they simply will not vote for the individual.

Comment: [The idea behind the policy for elections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/180276) is that allowing recently suspended candidates to run only leads to unnecessary "airing of dirty laundry"—I'd imagine similar reasoning would apply here.

Comment: @Doorknob On the other hand, being a room owner is much less of a responsibility than being a diamond moderator. A chat suspension is also much less of a punishment than a site suspension. I don't think it's necessary to bar recently-chat-suspended users from being nominated. If people try to create drama, the community can remove it, in accordance with the Be Nice policy.

Comment: @Doorknob I agree with Mego. People change (like I did from being a caret and stealth-ping spammer to being a reformed guy). I think we should give everyone a chance and if people think that an individual is not fit for being an RO, people are always free to downvote

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically query or search for chat users active during that time having a certain amount of rep, in order to find potential candidates?

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't know why you'd want to search by rep (it doesn't really have anything to do with ability to effectively moderate TNB), but looking at the [info page for TNB](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte) will give you an idea of when the users who are most frequently in TNB are online. To look at a specific user's activity, check their chat profile.

Comment: @Mego Well, we want someone who is active on PPCG as well.

Comment: I dislike the fact that being a room owner also disqualifies one from having *their* messages moderated.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ I don't know what leaps of logic you had to take to reach that blatantly incorrect conclusion.

Comment: Do we want to have [the First Past the Post system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting)? It is widely known to be ineffective.

Comment: How can we prevent "just anybody" from voting in these elections and rigging them?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ The mods will be taking care of the actual election phase, so you should direct any questions regarding it towards them.

Comment: @Doorknob can you address [this comment](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/new-tnb-room-owners-nominations-phase?noredirect=1#comment37483_11320)?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Unlike the democratic moderator elections, this is not an official nor formal "election," per se. After it's all said and done, we (the PPCG moderators) will review the votes and discussion and decide on appointing as many new room owners as we feel is necessary and best for the site (which may be based on other factors and not necessarily those with the most votes).

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, but perhaps a non-FPTP system would be fairer and provide more accurate data?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ it's not FPTP though, SE voting allows you to upvote/downvote any number of posts.

Comment: @Pavel still worse than STV

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ STV is not feasible without external tools, which is less-than-ideal (since external tools can't be verified and validated as easily as meta). Unless you actually have suggestions for how to make the election better, your complaints aren't helpful.

Comment: @Mego Google Forms with public results. Three questions, "who do you pick for X choice", invalid choices are thrown away. You can link to the spreadsheet in a way that results come in live.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ With that method, either anonymity is lost, or it's impossible to make sure that only site users vote, and only vote once.

Comment: @Mego or ask the SE Community Team for using their election platform

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ That's completely unreasonable.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Comments are not for extended discussion, please use a chatroom for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the nomination period has passed.

Comment: @Mego So is there a new one for the actual voting phase?

Comment: @mbomb007 The moderators will be taking care of the next phase. Last I heard, they haven't decided when it will happen yet: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35059037#35059037

Answer (score 26):

## Nomination for [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego)

- [Chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/169713/mego)
- Times online: essentially constantly (thanks to insomnia and PPCG addiction)

I (Mego) have been an active participant in all aspects of PPCG for over a year now. I ran in the [first moderator election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1), receiving quite a few votes. I am consistently active on the main site, on meta, and in chat. Notably, I pushed for the election of more room owners, and [proposed a popular standard for chat behavior](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11141/45941). All in all, I am very level-headed, and seek to improve and support this wonderful community whenever possible.

Comment: Is he active in chat during 5 AM - 2 PM UTC? [*Don't mistake posting activity with presence*](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/should-we-have-even-more-room-owners-for-the-nineteenth-byte/10920#comment35890_10920)

Comment: I'll accept this nomination, though I wish the nominator had put more effort into the nomination. @mbomb007 I almost always am keeping an eye on chat, even if I'm not actively participating (sometimes there just isn't anything to talk about).

Comment: For me, that UTC time corresponds to the time when I'm *least often* online. :/

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm an insomniac, so being awake in the middle of the night (11 PM - 8 AM my local time) isn't that unusual for me.

Answer (score 19):

## (Self-)Nomination for DJMcMayhem

I'll throw my own hat into the ring. *[Chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144962/djmcmayhem)*

I'm usually slightly active in 16-24 UTC and significantly more active in 0-6 UTC. I also frequently use chat from mobile, so if pinged I can respond fairly quickly if I'm not at my computer.

I would be honored to be a room owner for TNB. I have been actively participating in TNB for about one year now, as well as <s>participating in</s> feeding my addiction to PPCG and meta. I like to think that during that time I have been a friendly, welcoming, and mature voice, although I'd love to hear a third-party voice either agreeing or disagreeing with me.

PPCG/TNB is the best online community I've ever been a part of, and if there's anything I can do to make using chat a more pleasant place for everyone involved, I would be happy to.

Answer (score 16):

## (Self-)Nomination for minxomat

I second the notion that we need more room owners to cover the times mentioned in Mego's original proposal, in fact I was close to proposing this myself. During those times, I defintely notice the abscense of privileged chat members. Not in a way that there is a catastrophic amount of noise, but in a "hm, this is probably bad, I wish there would be a mod here right now to keep an eye on this" way.

When those quiet periods end, I want users to come back to an interesting transcript, with a high signal-to-noise ratio, as I mentioned in my original post on this issue "[We need to talk about chat](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/we-need-to-talk-about-chat)".

I'm always here during the periods in question (living in the time-zone in question helps), and I'm present in chat for most of the day, since it's basically pinned on all my PCs. Whether I'm level headed enough and all that comes with it, it's up to you to decide.

---

To add some qualification, I've been moderating chat and everything else (together with a team of great mods) in another coder-oriented community (with a bit more users than this site has) for over 5 years. I'm confident in saying that I've seen and handled almost every type of user/personality there is.

Answer (score 9):

## (Self-)Nomination for PhiNotPi

Right now, I am a student with strong interests in programming and music composition. You can almost always find me hiding in the Nineteenth Byte, where I spend a substantial amount of time. Five years ago, I found PPCG after reading the Wikipedia article about code golfing. Now, I no longer consider golfing my hobby, I consider PPCG my hobby. I have found that this website has one of the most interesting, intelligent, and respectable communities on the internet. It has been an absolute blast to work/play with you all, and I will be honored to serve on your room ownership team.

*1938 days a member.* I saw the creation and destruction of Sandbox Mk III, the freezing and thawing of the Nineteenth Byte, the rise and fall of code-trolling, the birth and death of the Fortnightly Challenges, and now I am witness to yet another transition. If there is one thing I have learned, it is that the journey is its own destination.

Miscellaneous other things I've been involved in, to demonstrate community involvement:

- I'm the artist behind the stunningly gorgeous 16x16px MS Paint [chat feed icons](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-278/new-sandboxed-posts).
- Quest For Tetris (with special thanks to about a dozen other users)
- unofficial PPCG [blog](https://medium.com/code-golf/)
- Ran in the previous moderator election (close but no cigar)
- [Chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/24697/phinotpi)

Answer (score 5):

## (Self-)Nomination for orlp

- [Chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/64910/orlp)
- Online during essentially any time due to varying sleep patterns.

I've been active on PPCG for 1.5 years now, and regularly hang out in the chat. You can expect permissive policing from me, but with a clear goal: stimulating intellectually engaging conversation in 19b. My main reason for applying as room owner is to improve the noise/signal ratio in the 19b. Math, golfing, mini-challenges, interesting observations: in. Memes, 'hi', 'anyone here?', avocads, bots: out.