# The Nineteenth Byte is getting more room owners. Cast your votes!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) is getting three additional room owners.

[You've had one week to nominate others or yourself](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11320/12012), and now it's time for the actual election.

These are the nominees, in alphabetical order.

- **DJMcMayhem**
  [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144962) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31716) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11326/12012) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11399/12012)
- **Mego**
  [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/169713) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45941) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11325/12012) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11400/12012)
- **mınxomaτ**
  [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/158822) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42643) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42643) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11327/12012) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11401/12012)
- **orlp**
  [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/64910) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11363/12012) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11402/12012)
- **PhiNotPi**
  [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/24697) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2867) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11328/12012) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11403/12012)

We've added a community wiki answer for each of them. You may vote on as many of them as you want, and the candidates are welcome to vote as freely as anyone else (including for themselves).

Voting will close after 7 days, on February 8 at 05:00 UTC. At the end of the election, the three candidates with the highest scores (upvotes minus downvotes) will be submitted to the moderators and current room owners for approval and instatement as new room owners.

**Best of luck to the candidates!**

Comment: A friendly reminder: serial voting restrictions apply on meta as well, and may be triggered if you upvote too many nominations or downvote too many nominations in a short period of time. Make sure you check if any of your votes got reversed before the week is over.

Answer (score 43):

## [Mego](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/169713)

[image]

Chat user since 2015-10-08.

315 messages this week. 503 messages last week. 453 messages per week.

Comment: I think Mego will make for a very effective TNB owner, judging from their activity in the past.

Answer (score 41):

## [DJMcMayhem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144962)

[image]

Chat user since 2015-04-07.

340 messages this week. 457 messages last week. 409 messages per week.

Answer (score 29):

## [mınxomaτ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/158822)

[image]

Chat user since 2015-08-03.

248 messages this week. 238 messages last week. 202 messages per week.

Answer (score 27):

## [PhiNotPi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/24697)

[image]

Chat user since 2011-10-06.

14 messages this week. 156 messages last week. 60 messages per week.

Answer (score 17):

## [orlp](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/64910)

[image]

Chat user since 2013-02-04.

333 messages this week. 175 messages last week. 236 messages per week.