# Please welcome The Nineteenth Byte's newest room owners!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[You've cast your votes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11398/12012) and elected the following three members of our community as room owners of our primary chat room, [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

[image] [image] [image]

They have been appointed, effective immediately. Please join us in thanking them for volunteering, and may the odds be ever in their favor.

Comment: Don't forget to swing by Martin's house to get your barcode tattoo. I know, I know... they didn't tell me about it until I'd agreed either.

Comment: @Geobits Mine says 47... I think everyone should be concerned.

Comment: Actually I don't think it was effective immediately. I think that, once the votes were locked, the owners should have been instantaneously appointed. Was there any reason to not immediately appoint them?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer From the election post: `At the end of the election, the three candidates with the highest scores (upvotes minus downvotes) will be submitted to the moderators and current room owners for approval and instatement as new room owners.` It took time for all of the moderators and then-current room owners to see and approve the selections.

Comment: @Mego What questioned me is how much it took everyone to approve the candidates.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It took less than 24 hours. That's actually a bit surprising, considering how many different timezones the moderators and then-current room owners occupy, and how they are frequently very busy.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer *effective immediately* refers to the annoncement, not the election results.

Comment: @Dennis I know, I was referring to the delay before this announcement was posted though. I don't know the exact reason there needs to be approval though, since the community has already voted. Please reply in chat.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Because a federal republic is the best kind of government. :P

Comment: Why does this remind me of the hunger games?

Answer (score 10):

It's an honor to be chosen by the community to be a room owner of The Nineteenth Byte. I've had many good experiences in TNB, and I hope to help others have good experiences as well.

Comment: What he said :)