# Should we have even even more room owners for The Nineteenth Byte?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, moderation

[4 years ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/please-welcome-the-nineteenth-bytes-newest-room-owners), we voted on and appointed additional room owners for [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). That was the most recent time TNB has had new room owners. Currently, only 2 of the room owners are able to be pinged if needed, and one of those 2 hasn't been active since October 2020.

The need for active room owners isn't pressing - star spam, kicks, etc. are relatively rare nowadays - but it'd still be nice to have a few around if and when needed.

Comment: [Previous discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/should-we-have-even-more-room-owners-for-the-nineteenth-byte)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, we should have more room owners *again*

I think the answer is "yes" for the same reason to why we have community mod elections periodically. Users come and go, and mods and chatroom owners are no exceptions. We've been electing new mods every 2-3 years, and still we once suffered from the shortage of active mods.

We don't have that many incidents that require intervention of a mod or RO, but it is still annoying when such an incident does happen and cannot be handled soon enough.

---

I guess we can do an election for new ROs like we did 4 years ago. Here is a copy of the requirements proposed back then:

> - Contributes positively and regularly to chat (more signal than noise)
> - Frequently active during 5 AM - 2 PM UTC (when other room owners and moderators often aren't)
> - Levelheaded and reasonable (essentially the same things we want in community moderators)
> - Not currently a community moderator (though since I am in the minority in the opinion that adding community moderators as room owners doesn't help alleviate the burden of moderation, this is more of a personal preference than a requirement)

most of which are sensible (except for the "time of activity" one, which is not needed this time IMO).